# ros2_control_node crashes abruptly with error "what(): Taking data from action server but nothing is ready

Tags: moveit, ros2-control, ros-iron

I am building an application with ros2 iron using moveit and ros2control.

The application I created usually works without errors, but "sometimes" it crashes abruptly.

The errors at that time are as follows.

I would appreciate any insight you can give me.

```
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1705464328.148369918] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Controller '/A_joint_trajectory_controller' successfully finished 
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1705464328.148765774] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Controller '/B_joint_trajectory_controller' successfully finished 
[ros2_control_node-3] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' 
[ros2_control_node-3] what(): Taking data from action server but nothing is ready 
[ros2_control_node-3] Stack trace (most recent call last): 
[ros2_control_node-3] #15 Object "", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #14 Object "/opt/ros/iron/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x55d77ba19e04, in _start 
[ros2_control_node-3] #13 Source "../csu/libc-start.c", line 392, in __libc_start_main_impl [0x7f9969029e3f] 
[ros2_control_node-3] #12 Source "../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h", line 58, in__libc_start_call_main [0x7f9969029d8f] 
[ros2_control_node-3] #11 Object "/opt/ros/iron/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x55d77ba199ef, in main 
[ros2_control_node-3] #10 Object "/opt/ros/iron/lib/librclcpp.so", at 0x7f996990ee14, in rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor::spin() 
[ros2_control_node-3] #9 Object "/opt/ros/iron/lib/librclcpp.so", at 0x7f996990e9b1, in rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor::run(unsigned long) 
[ros2_control_node-3] #8 Object "/opt/ros/iron/lib/librclcpp.so", at 0x7f99699059fe, in rclcpp::Executor::get_next_ready_executable_from_map(rclcpp::AnyExecutable&, std::map<std::weak_ptrrclcpp::CallbackGroup, std::weak_ptrrclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface, std::owner_less<std::weak_ptrrclcpp::CallbackGroup >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::weak_ptrrclcpp::CallbackGroup const, std::weak_ptrrclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface > > > const&) 
[ros2_control_node-3] #7 Object "/opt/ros/iron/lib/librclcpp_action.so", at 0x7f99345c4785, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #6 Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f99694ae4d7, in __cxa_throw 
[ros2_control_node-3] #5 Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f99694ae276, in std::terminate() 
[ros2_control_node-3] #4 Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f99694ae20b, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #3 Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f99694a2b9d, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #2 Source "./stdlib/abort.c", line 79, in abort [0x7f99690287f2] 
[ros2_control_node-3] #1 Source "../sysdeps/posix/raise.c", line 26, in raise [0x7f9969042475] 
[ros2_control_node-3] #0 | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 89, in__pthread_kill_internal 
[ros2_control_node-3] | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 78, in __pthread_kill_implementation 
[ros2_control_node-3] Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 44, in__pthread_kill [0x7f99690969fc] 
[ros2_control_node-3] Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 180811 1000) 
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-3]: process has died [pid 180811, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/iron/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_44ibrmz5 --params-file /home/user/ros2_ws/***/ros2_control_config.yaml'].
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug, can you please report it in [ros2_controllers repo](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/issues)?

Comment: Thank you.I will report it there.